# Determining if a random string has a letter in it

Tags: java

Is their a way to check if a random letter of upper or lower case value is equal to another string in java?

```
String p = "(a)";
if(p.equals("(" + RANDOM lETTTER + ")"){
}
```

This is an example of the code I'm typing
Sorry I forgot to mention this must work for any letter. all at once.

Comment: What's wrong with what you posted? Presumably you wanted `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: Or just `p.contains(randomLetter.toLowerCase())` ... is there an actual question here?

Comment: You could use a regular expression depending on the complexity of your problem

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish. The title says "random string"; the example has "random letter". Are you trying to check if some unknown string contains at least one letter (upper or lower case)? Or that the string has exactly one letter? Or that it has a specific letter, unknown at coding time? Something else? Please provide more context for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method from [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
String inputString = "Hello, Good Morning";
String randomLetter = "M";

  if(inputString.contains(randomLetter)) {
  // Do whatever you want
  }
```

If you want to do case insensitive check then  use [toLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) on both `inputString` and `randomLetter` then it becomes..

```
  if(inputString.toLowerCase().contains(randomLetter.toLowerCase())) {
    // Do whatever you want
  }
```